# Problems facing while running codeception acceptance tests on Mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception

I am using phpStorm IDE with composer and codeception to write selenium acceptance tests in my mac machine.But I couldn't able to run my tests.

I started my Selenium Stand alone jar and chromedriver in my mac machine using the below command.

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/Users/krishna/Downloads/chromedriverNewChrome" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

Below is the console information and not sure if the Chrome driver is running or not.

00:34:19.637 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
00:34:19.722 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2019-02-08 00:34:19.777:INFO::main: Logging initialized @348ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
00:34:19.985 INFO [WebDriverServlet.] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
00:34:20.086 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444

```
<?php
use \AcceptanceTester;

class IndexTest

{

    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I){}

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnUrl('http://codeception.com');
        $I->amOnPage('/quickstart'); // moves to http://codeception.com/quickstart
    }
}
```

acceptance.yml file

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
              url: 'http://localhost/'
              window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
              port: 43008
              browser: chrome
```

Running in the following way:

```
Go to PhpStorm>Run>EditConfiguration>Codeception>Select Type as acceptance tests and run it.
```

I see following error in the console after I run the tests.

Testing started at 00:50 ...
/usr/bin/php /private/var/folders/4v/cltv5gzs79n6v77b53zw52z00000gn/T/ide-codeception.php run --report -o "reporters: report: PhpStorm_Codeception_ReportPrinter" --no-ansi --no-interaction -c /Users/kabothu/PhpstormProjects/CodeCeptionAutomation/codeception.yml acceptance

Warning: Declaration of PhpStorm_Codeception_ReportPrinter::writeProgress($progress): void should be compatible with PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter::writeProgress(string $progress): void in /private/var/folders/4v/cltv5gzs79n6v77b53zw52z00000gn/T/ide-codeception_24_70.php on line 2
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.5.3
Powered by PHPUnit 7.5.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed:

Time: 148 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

No tests executed!

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

You named your test class `IndexTest`, it would work if it extended `PhpUnit\Framework\TestCase` or `Codeception\Test\Unit`.
However your test code shows that you wanted to implement test in Cest format,
to get it working you must rename your test class to `IndexCest`and file to `IndexCest.php`.